# How to execute php in onclick button

Tags: php, html

Hello need help to run the following php in a html.

```
function runMyFunction(){
      $_SESSION["identificate"] = 'no';
      session_destroy();
      header('Location: Login.html');
}
---------------------------------------------------------
 <div id="foo">
    <button type="button" onclick="runMyFunction()">Logout

    </button>
 </div>
```

Thanks

Comment: PHP is a serverside language. This means it's performed before the visitor sees the output in the browser. The best solution would be to create a redirect with Javascript towards the php file and use `header('location: .. ')` to send them back again or use Ajax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should execute an `ajax` call with the help of `jQuery`.
We can use the shorthand method `.post` to issue a post request directly.

First put the `php` code in a separate file, called `logout.php`

**logout.php**

```
function runMyFunction(){
      $_SESSION["identificate"] = 'no';
      session_destroy();

      //header('Location: Login.html'); we will move the redirect to the success handler of the ajax call
}

//call the function
runMyFunction();
```

Then in the `html`, include `jquery` and add a `script` block like below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#foo button").click(function(){
        $.post( "logout.php", function( data ) {
            console.log("success");
            window.location = "login.html"; // redirect moved here, after the logout happened successfully
        });
    })
});
</script>
```

You can remove the `onclick` attribute from the button, so your `button` html will become this

```
<button type="button">Logout</button>
```

This is how you include `jQuery`

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: If you're going to use `$("#foo button")` then the button requires an id.

Comment: `foo` is the id of the div containing the button, button doesn't need id. Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: ah, you're probably right Alex. My mistake ;-)

Comment: edited the answer to move the redirect in the ajax success callback

Comment: Im sorry i am working with php and html so i don't know much about js and jquery. That script you made will modify like what my button 'foo' will do?
where in that script do i write my "runMyfunction()" so that when i click the button it will execute it?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your last question. What happens, in simple terms, is that when you click on the button, you execute the php function, in the background :)

Comment: what  i mean is that i don't see in the script the name of my function called "runMyfuntion()", so i was wondering if i should replace it somewhere. Should i replace "logout.php" for runmyfunction?

Comment: the function is in the separate php file, the function is called inside the php file when it is executed via the `.post` request. Read the answer and the comments inside

Comment: Thanks you ! it worked

Comment: Sorry for bothering you again but the function in the php file is not running it is just like the one your wrote. The script is working tho because the page is redirected. What could be going wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96437/discussion-between-alex-andrei-and-polo-d-vargas).